# How to display AJAX results in a HTML drop down menu

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am creating a few drop down menus that populate depending on the previous drop down value selected.

So far I am able to successfully use ajax to grab data from the php script, however, I am not sure how to append that data to the second drop down called AREAS.

```
HTML / Javascript / AJAX
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>IPSLA Report</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeSelections() {
      var departments = document.selections.department;
      var areas = document.selections.areas;
      var months = document.selections.months;
      var years = document.selections.years;
      var s = document.getElementById("department");

      switch(departments.selectedIndex) {
        case 0:
          areas.options.length = 0;
          months.options.length = 0;
          years.options.length = 0;

          areas.options[0] = new Option("Select an Area");
          months.options[0] = new Option("Select a Month");
          years.options[0] = new Option("Select a Year");
          departments.options[0].selected = true;
          break;

        default:
          months.options.length = 0;
          years.options.length = 0;

          months.options[0] = new Option("Select a Month");
          years.options[0] = new Option("Select a Year");

          var pass = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text;
          ajaxFunction(pass);
      }

    }


    function ajaxFunction(pass) {

    var ajaxRequest;
      try {
         ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      catch(e) {
        try {
          ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObjext("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e) {
          try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObjext("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          catch(e) {
            alert("Please use another browser");
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
          var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById("areas");
          if (ajaxDisplay != null) {
          ajaxDisplay.options.selectedIndex.text = ajaxRequest.responseText;
          }
          else {
            document.write("NULL!!!");
          }
        }
      }

      if (pass == "CRAN") {
        var active_id = '0';
      }

      var queryString = "?active_id=" + active_id;
      ajaxRequest.open("GET","db_connect.php" + queryString, true);
      ajaxRequest.send(null);

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="select">
        <form name="selections" id="selections" action="">
          <select name="department" id="department" onChange="changeSelections()">
            <option value="none">Select Department</option>
            <option value="none">CRAN</option>
            <option value="none">BackBone</option>
            <option value="none">Datacenter</option>
            <option value="none">Enterprise</option>
          </select>


          <select name="areas" id="areas" onChange="changeMonth()">
            <option value="none">Select an Area</option>
          </select>

          <select name="months" id="months" onChange="changeYear()">
            <option value="none">Select a Month</option>
          </select>

          <select name="years" id="years" onChange="go(this)">
            <option value="none">Select a Year</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>


      <div id="image">

      </div>


      <div id="incidents">

      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

PHP Script
<?php
  $host = "";
  $dbName = "";
  $username = "";
  $password = "";

  $conn = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
  $db = mysql_select_db($dbName,$conn);

  $dept_id = $_GET['id'];

  $area_query = "SELECT area_name FROM incident_area WHERE FK_dept= '$dept_id'";
  $area_result = mysql_query($area_query);

 $options = "";
  while ($area_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($area_result)) {
     #$options .= '<option value="'.$area_row['area_name'].'">'.$area_row['area_name'].'</option>';
      $options .= $area_row['area_name'];
  }
 echo $options;

?>
~
```

So, basically I just need to know how to append the values gathered by AJAX to the drop down menu "areas".

Comment: no raw `XMLHttpRequest`, strongly recommended jQuery.

Comment: @SiweiShen - What is the equivalent in jQuery?  Resource that you could point me to?

Comment: google its official website, there are lots of documents. see : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ . first of all, check out how its 'selector' works, then ,checkout its 'ajax' methods. very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [site](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html) helped me big time, also [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html). Jquery is the way to go. It'll allow you to append data into html and create the dynamic drop-down you're looking for.

```
Javascript
// needs hotlink to jquery file, for library to work right. 
var options = "";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("./file.php", { postVariableInPHPFile: "some string" }, function(data) {
        options = data; // data is the return from the AJAX call 
    });
});
```

Depending on how much data you're expecting from your PHP call, you may have to concatenate your results how ever you prefer to get a full list.

Comment: Is it possible to set the data sent to the server to the text of the selected item?

`var $data = $('areas option:selected').text();
data: $data`

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to a click function for the dropdown. You're trying to do two different things, one populate the dropdown from ajax, and also send the selection as data to ajax. Unless you're sending the selection from a previous dropdown.

Are you having dropdown1 produce some choice -> send that selection as data to the ajax to create the next dropdown?


Also, you're confusing your variable decleration in js with php
javascript: var varName = "string";
php: $varName = "string";

Comment: User selects something from dropdown 1 -> the selection text is sent to php and used to gather data to be populated in the second dropdown -> user selected something from dropdown 2 -> etc... etc...

Comment: Assuming you have your PHP setup to take POST data for the query, just have your dropdown1 javascript do something like

    `$("#dropdown1 option").is("selected").text();`

that will get you the text of the selected option, use that for your PHP ajax request